# cookie issue with firefox, jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, firefox, cookies

Hi guys I have a problem with cookies on firefox I'm submitting a form using jquery and on server side the controller am calling sets a cookie, i was not even sure if that possible but it seems working fine with chrome and not on firefox, however on localhost it works fine for both firefox and chrome 
here is my code
Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                 $("#vote-button").click(function() {
                    $('.ui-button').fadeOut();


                  /*var dataString = 'vote='+ vote + '&id=' + id + '&ip=' + ip + '&code=' + code;*/

                  $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "<?php echo site_url()?>/vote",
                          data: $('#hate-form').serialize(),
                          success: function() {
                          $('.vote-box').html("<p> Thanks for voting :) </p>").fadein("slow");}

                          });
                          return false;
                          });

                </script>
```

and this in my controller Vote:

```
    $this->load->model('site_model');
$this->site_model->add_vote($id,$vote,$inside);    
$cookname ='motriba_'.$id; 
    $current_time = time();
    $exp = $current_time + 86400 - ($current_time % 86400); //midnight time 
setcookie($cookname,$id,$exp);
```

Comment: Is it possible that the URL returned by site_url() is not the same as the URL in the browser (i.e. one would be example.com, and the other www.example.com)?

Comment: Check the sources of the page. The line 'url: "<?php echo site_url()?>/vote",' should show what URL is setting the cookie. Make sure it is the same as the URL in Firefox address bar

Comment: you are right there were double slashes //, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to mark this post as answered:

In your code, check that 'url: "< ?php echo site_url()?>/vote",' returns the same URL as the URL in Firefox address bar.